# Dates repeating in Google line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, line

I'd like to create a Google line chart drawing (for stocks data) that will have data points for every market year.  But I only want the years to appear once.  Like this:

[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10FaA.png)

But when I try, I get a result with repeating years like this:

[incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X1DV.png)

Finally, here's a look at how I'm loading the data and the options I'm using:

[Chart data and options.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIkUw.png)

Comment: Excuse my poor formatting above. This is the first question I've asked.  So there's no way to edit this? Hmm.  Anyway, I'd appreciate any help that anyone can provide with this. Thanks.

Comment: You can edit the question by clicking on the `Edit` link below the question.  Please make sure to paste your code into the question as text instead of an image.